# MVC 3, Razor, EF - Create View which allows adding children dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have searched high and low for an example of editing a parents children within the create view but none of the examples I have found mention/discuss this functionality the information I have found has either been out of date or varies greatly. I have a Product and it can have multiple packages which should be added dynamically also need to be able to add categories. What is the correct way of implementing this functionality? In the Create view the product hasnt been saved yet so I would guess has no id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) by Steve Sanderson which illustrates a state of the art example of how to achieve this. It uses the WebForms view engine but it would be trivial to translate it to Razor.